# How to delete all passwords saved on my google account?

Tags: google-account, google-chrome, google-passwords

I just found out, that without ever being asked Google stored a lot of my passwords in my google account. Most of them come back from when I was a kid and used Google Chrome for a while. I found these at passwords.google.com.

I want to delete all the passwords and accounts from the list. It allows me to delete one by one, but that's quite tedious. It's a 3 click process with loading time delays.

How to delete all the passwords?

Comment: Came here in order to perform a clean Google password import/replace from a csv file. Without Chrome, an operation that might take 10 seconds ended up in hours, unfortunately. The extra payload was that some passwords were not being copied with "_A password is already saved_" notification for non-matching passwords.

Answer (score 7):

One possible solution is

1. Click on the 3 vertical dots in the upper right corner
2. Click "More Tools" > "Clear Browsing Data"
3. On the new page, change the time frame to "All Time"
4. Click "Advanced"
5. Select "Passwords" before clicking on "Clear Data"

There is no way to restore passwords after doing this to my knowledge.

Source: https://support.google.com/accounts/thread/3509905?hl=en

Comment: After doing this, I still have all my passwords available at https://passwords.google.com/. How do I clear them from there as well?

Comment: If this doesn't delete them from  passwords.google.com, then your only option is to delete them manually, one at a time. 
Theoretically, you could use the password import/export to override all existing passwords to make the data useless, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: Note, that this does not work using Edge, you have to use Chrome. Installing Chrome solved it for me. The shortcut on macOS is Command+Shift+Backspace btw.

Answer (score 0):

This [recommended answer](https://support.google.com/accounts/thread/3509905?hl=en&msgid=11927181) from 2019 on the Google's support worked for me today (I only tested the Chrome Desktop way):

> 1. Go to https://www.google.com/settings/chrome/sync and Reset Sync
> 2. This will disconnect syncing on all your devices temporarily and deletes passwords on the server side
> 3. Now you have to go device by device and bulk delete passwords
>
>    - On Chrome Desktop: Ctrl+Shift+Del --> Advanced --> Time Range: All time --> Select Passwords only --> Clear data
>    - On Chrome Mobile: Settings --> Privacy --> Clear Browsing Data --> Advanced --> Time range: All time --> Select Saved passwords only --> Clear data
> 4. After you bulk deleted passwords from the device, you can turn back on syncing: Settings --> Turn on sync

Currently, the button in https://www.google.com/settings/chrome/sync UI changed from `Reset Sync` text to `CLEAR DATA`. The companion message reads:

> This will clear your Chrome data from your Google Account. This won't clear any data from your devices.

On the 4th step you'll need to log in again to your account, and the data you didn't remove from your devices will be synced.

Comment: What nobody tells you here is that you must close chrome and restart it after you clear the passwords or they will not be removed.

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/1267772/543283): Chrome > ctrl+shift+delete > clear browsing data > advanced